# how to enable firefox addons in Ghost.py

Tags: python, qwebkit, ghost.py

Is it possible to run imacro firefox script inside ghost.py?
I want to automate heavy ajax sites.

I'm trying this:

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost(plugins_enabled=True,plugin_path=['C:\Documents and Settings\my\Desktop\addons\addon-3863-latest.xpi'],)
```

Answer (score 1):

Within Ghost.py you would find the code snippet:

```
if plugin_path:
  for p in plugin_path:
    Ghost._app.addLibraryPath(p)
```

From the look of things, it's expecting a path ([addLibraryPath](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QCoreApplication.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath)) and would do its discoveries by itself. So, give it a path containing the .xpi

**Note**: this isn't tested.

On my Windows 10, I typed this into a Windows address bar:

> %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

I then saw a folder named "**kswjuot9.default**" (it might be named another things on your PC) and clicked it. Finally, I found a folder named "**extensions**".

Try to give Ghost.py the full address of this "**extensions**" folder. I would also recommend that you use forward slashes e.g.

> C:/Users/iChux/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/kswjuot9.default/extensions

I saw an [online link](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/install-firefox-flash-plugin-manually-on-windows-7/) on dealing with how to extract the .xpi file